# How is memory properly allocated?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

so I am learning and trying to figure out memory allocation in c, in this piece of code, is the memory allocated correctly or no? Do I need to allocate the array too or is the array already allocated because everything that user inputs goes to the array(will be stored in the array)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int i;
    int arr[20];
    int b;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &b;

    ptr = (int*) malloc(20 *sizeof(int));

    //find largest element in array
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf(" No memory allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }


    for (i = 0; i < b; ++i) {
        printf("Enter number%d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < b; ++i) {
        if (arr[0] < arr[i])
            arr[0] = arr[i];
    }
    free(ptr);
    printf("Largest element = %d", arr[0]);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you allocate memory but do not use it. arr and ptr have no relationship to each other

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the `malloc` call:

```
ptr = malloc( 20 * sizeof *ptr );
```

You don’t need to cast the result of `malloc` unless you using an *ancient* pre-C89 implementation or C++ (in which case you should use `new/delete` instead of `malloc/free`, or more preferably a container type like `vector`).

`sizeof *ptr` is equivalent to `sizeof (int)` in this case.

However, you aren’t actually using that memory - you allocate it and free it, but you never write anything to it.

You initially assign `&b` to `ptr`, but then you overwrite it with the result of the `malloc` call, so if you’re expecting that memory to be attached to `b` somehow, be aware that it isn’t.